# Arbitrary image transform using opengl

Tags: opengl, image-processing

I need to transfer an image by mapping each pixel in input image to a place on output image.

For example point (xi,yi) on input image should be mapped into point (xo,yo). To find the place of point on output image, I have a look up table.

It is easy to do it in C/C++, but it is very slow. Is there any way that I can do it using OpenGL shader so it gate the speed increase of GPU on target system?

How can I speed up this process if I can not use opengl?

### Edit 1

Mock sample c/c++ code:

```
class Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
}

Point LUT[w,h];   // would hold LUT

void Transform(image in,image out)
{
     for(int x=0;x<w;x++)
     {
          for(int y=0;y<h;y++)
          {
                color pixelColor=in.GetPixelColor(x,y);
                out.PutPixelColor(LUT[x,y].x,LUT[x,y].y),pixelColor);
          }
     }
}

void main()
{
  image in,out;
  ReadLUT(LUT);    // read LUT from file and fill LUT table
  ReadImage(in);   // read input image.

  Transform(in,out);   // transform image based on LUT
  SaveImage(out);      // write output image
```

}

Comment: This is a perfectly parallelizable task. This is basically what the GPU can do way better than the CPU. What you could do utilizing OpenGL is the following: Draw a quad with the image's dimensions. In the pixel shader determine the source pixel and set it to the output.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: Can you please give some sample code or some refernces that I can read more about how to do this.

Comment: What kind of pattern are you using in the table? You could be having bad cache performance. Have you actually done this in C++ and found it to be slow or are you guessing? GPUs won't necessarily make something like this faster depending on image size, what the lookup table looks like etc. especially once you factor in the roundtrip costs (less if you want to keep it on the GPU.)

Comment: @JacobParker: I did a test and it takes around 1 minutes to do the transform with a CPU. I like to see how long would it takes to do this on a GPU using shader. The image size is relatively big (50MPixel).

Comment: @mans I'm interested in seeing your actual C++ code/hearing what your lookup table looks like. I notice in your pseudo-code you are iterating over y inside the loop iterating over x - do you know how caches work? Are you paying attention to memory access patterns?

Comment: @JacobParker: The code is for illustration only. In code that I have which is a bit more complex than this, I take care of cash and iterate over x and y in a way that I read from the memory in an increasing fashon (so there was not any need to invaldate cash which hold LUT). Also I did not use a real image, but I get a refernce to its byte data and worked there. Just looks to see how fast can I run it on GPU using shader if it is possible as the problem is a good parallel problem.